# Calculate number of weeks , days and hours from milliseconds

Tags: javascript, date, hour, days

There were many similar questions around but none addressed this calculation. Using javascript i it is easy to find the number of milliseconds diff b/w 2 dates for ex:

```
var mil = Math.floor(new Date("1/1/2012")  - new Date("1/7/2012"))
```

`mil` is assigned `518400000`

to get weeks i would do below

```
var weeks = mil / (1000*7*24*60*60);
```

in the above example it exactly fits `1` week. For other possible inputs i would like to get output as ex:

```
n Weeks, y days , z hours
```

So i did `mil % (1000*7*24*3600)` to get the modulus and from the remainder calculate number of days. but astonishingly this was answer i got from console
`1 weeks , 6 days` seems the week calculated before is also accounted for days again.

#### How should i calculate these correctly?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
var seconds = (mil / 1000) | 0;
mil -= seconds * 1000;

var minutes = (seconds / 60) | 0;
seconds -= minutes * 60;

var hours = (minutes / 60) | 0;
minutes -= hours * 60;

var days = (hours / 24) | 0;
hours -= days * 24;

var weeks = (days / 7) | 0;
days -= weeks * 7;
```

Assuming `mils` is non-negative, this leaves `mils` in the range [0, 1000), leaves `minutes` and `seconds` in the range [0, 60), leaves `hours` in the range [0, 24), and leaves `days` in the range [0, 7).

Comment: this was more perfect of calculation i quickly put a JSBin and it works thanks http://jsbin.com/usigit/4/

Comment: could you improve this version to include Years and Months for completeness.

Comment: @Deeptechtons, no.  Months and years are not equal in length.

Comment: i certainly do agree ;) i tried a hand but it had become more complex due to Leap years, unequal days in month. If only all months had 30 days LOL

Comment: @Deeptechtons, yeah.  The history of [calendar reform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calendar_reform#Proposals) is a long and frustrating one though :)

Answer (score 6):

There should be 6 days between them, not one week. Your weeks calculation needs to round down:

```
var weeks = Math.floor(mil / (1000 * 7 * 24 * 60 * 60));
```

Also, your milliseconds are negative; you want either

```
var mil = new Date("1/7/2012") - new Date("1/1/2012");
```

or

```
var weeks = Math.floor(Math.abs(mil) / (1000 * 7 * 24 * 60 * 60));
```